# Did Rust changed the borrowing rules?

Tags: rust

I was reading [The Rust Programming Language book 2nd edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/second-edition/). In the [Understanding Ownership chapter, page 95](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references), it was saying that you can't have 2 mutable references.

But when I tried this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hi, mom!");

    let _r1 = &s;
    let _r2 = &s;

    let _r3 = &mut s;
    let _r4 = &mut s;
}
```

It worked and compiled with no error.

Shouldn't it give me a compile error?

Comment: tl;dr: Yes, kind of. The underlying borrowing rules have not changed (as evidenced by the fact you can make this code compile by adding enough `{` and `}`), but the compiler is smarter now about how it applies them.

Comment: References are now treated as in-scope only up until their last use (and not the entire scope in which they exist), so as long as the first and last uses of `_r3` and of `_r4` don't intersect, you won't have a problem.

Comment: The new book [uses the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references), for this reason.